# How to convert a template definition into a class

Tags: c++, class, templates, arduino

The following code works when used without C++ classes (Arduino code);

```
MIDI_CREATE_INSTANCE(HardwareSerial, Serial1, midiA);
```

This creates a variable midiA with the correct type. The macro definition is:

```
#define MIDI_CREATE_INSTANCE(Type, SerialPort, Name)                            \
    midi::MidiInterface<Type> Name((Type&)SerialPort);
```

However, I want to use this inside a class (to create a class variable midiA), but I cannot get it to work.

What I have now is:

```
class MidiHandler
{
    midi::MidiInterface<(HardwareSerial&) Serial1)> midiA;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
MidiHandler.h: 23:39: error: type\value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class SerialPort, class _Settings> class midi::MidiInterface
  midi*: MidiInterface<((HardwareSerial&)Serial1)> midiA
```

I think I might need to add the template to the class MidiHandler, also I wonder if I need to initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: Can't you use `std::function`?

Comment: @user0042 Never saw it before, but it looks for function pointers only.

Comment: You can use `std::function` for callables of all kind: function pointers, functor classes, lambda expressions.

Comment: Ok, I have to read further about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have an Arduino to compile and test this, but from the pure C++ point of view, I would declare the member in the class declaration and initialize it in the constructor. Like this:

```
class MidiHandler
{
public:
    MidiHandler(HardwareSerial& serial_port)
        : midiA(serial_port)
    { }

private:
    midi::MidiInterface<HardwareSerial> midiA;
};
```

Then, instantiate the class like this:

```
MidiHandler handler((HardwareSerial&) Serial1);
```

DETAIL:

The `MidiHandler` class has a member variable named `midiA` of type `midi::MidiInterface<HardwareSerial>`, which is a template with one template parameter (the `Type` parameter from the macro). `HardwareSerial` is used as the value for the template parameter.

The type `midi::MidiInterface<HardwareSerial>` has a constructor requiring one parameter of type `HardwareSerial&`. Therefore, `MidiHandler::MidiHandler`, the `MidiHandler` class constructor, needs a parameter of the same type to be used to construct `midiA`.

Finally, `Serial1` is passed as the constructor parameter to `handler`. `Serial1` must be of type `HardwareSerial&` or convertible to it. The C stile cast, `(HardwareSerial&)`, may or may not be needed depending on the type of Serial1, but I put it there since the macro had it.

Comment: Thank you (including the reason behind it).

The code I now have (and works I will put as a separate answer) but of course I upvoted/accepted yours

Answer (score 1):

As is shown in the define:

`#define MIDI_CREATE_INSTANCE(Type, SerialPort, Name)
midi::MidiInterface<Type> Name((Type&)SerialPort);`

So substituting in Your values should be:

`midi::MidiInterface<HardwareSerial> midiA((HardwareSerial&)Serial1);`

Answer (score 0):

Answer as result of the accepted answer by Luis Guzman:

In header file:

```
midi::MidiInterface<HardwareSerial> midiA;
midi::MidiInterface<HardwareSerial> midiB;
midi::MidiInterface<HardwareSerial> midiC;
```

In constructor:

```
MidiHandler::MidiHandler()
: midiA(Serial1),
  midiB(Serial2),
  midiC(Serial3)
```